# Converting Indonesian (id-ID) Date To English (en-US) Date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing problem while converting Indonesian Date to English Date.
Ex : I got an Date which is in Indonesian Language `i.e 24/mars/1958`
so I have to convert this date to English Date `i.e 24/mar/1958` I tried to convert the date by using following code

```
string date = "24/mars/1958";
string newDate = DateTime.Parse(date, new CultureInfo("id-ID")).ToShortDateString();
```

but the above code is throwing error
so can any one let me know how to convert this date to English Date

Thanks in Advance
  Nitesh Katare

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` Method.

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact is not working its returning
1/1/0001 might be it has some Error in converting
Im using following Code

DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo(""en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtNew);

Comment: Why are you using "en-GB" as your culture.  That doesn't sound like it would be the correct Indonesian culture.  Thats English-Great Britain if I am not mistaken.  So their calendar I would hope would be simply dd/mm/yyy en-US is mm/dd/yyyy